# How to refer from child class to child class of another class

Tags: python, inheritance

I know the title of the question is very confusing. I couldn't come up with anything meaningful. Let me explain it.

I have two classes, let's call them A and B:

```
class A(object):
    def get_instance_of_b():
        return B()

class B(object):
    pass
```

In it I have a method that refers to instance of class B.

I have 4 classes that inherit from A and another 4 classes that inherit from class B. Now what I want is to avoid rewriting *get_instance_of_b()* method. Class A1 (child of A) should get an instance of B1 (child of B) and so on.

What is the best way to do it? Or maybe I'm going wrong with classes structure?

To give a context to what my classes do: class A processes data and class B validates input parameters. All children of class A share some general parameters but children classes also have their own specific parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an explicit mapping of your `A` classes (your "processors") to your `B` classes (your "validators"), and do the lookup that way.

```
class A(object):
    def get_validator(self):
        return validators[self.__class__]()

class A1(A):
    ...

class B(object):
    ...

class B1(B):
    ...

validators = {A:B, A1:B1}
```

And use as such:

```
>>> a1 = A1()
>>> a1.get_validator()
<__main__.B1 object at ...>
```